# How to send a http request through a program developed in C?

Tags: c, http

As you read in the title, for example, i wanna login to my account in StackOverflow by sending the E-mail and password through a program developed in c language, so all what i have to do is to enter the required data (E-mail, password) in my program and after refreshing the webpage in the browser, i'm directly connected to my account.
If it's not possible in C, have you other suggestions?.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a browser plug-in for this? That would be my initial thought as I wonder if you realize the browser data that has to be updated here too.

Comment: @JB but, is it possible to develop a browser plug-in with C?.

Answer (score 5):

1. Pick a [Http library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221857/good-lightweight-library-for-http-post-get-for-c).
2. Use it to call on [Stack Exchange's public Web API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What if i wanna login to facebook, gmail, etc.?, is that the API is necessary for such operations?.

Comment: Google is your friend @Mehdi. I recommend searching to see if those companies have public Web APIs too. So, no. You can't log into Facebook with Stack Exchange's API, but you will use Http to do so.